# Is it possible to restrict the values that can be used in an editable datatable in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have an editable datatable in Shiny. In the table there is a column that has numeric values that the user can edit. This works fine and I have found much information on how to restrict which rows/columns can be edited (not used in the example below).

The problem I am encoutnering is that I need a way to restrict the *values* that a user can input into the editable cells. For example, when the data for the table is originally uploaded all values in the first column are some value of 10^x (i.e. 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc.). I need to be able to restrict the values of the cell so that when the user clicks the up or down arrow in the editable cell, it maintains that restriction. In the example below, when the original value in column 1 is 10, if I click up or down on the arrow the number changes to 11 or 9, respectively. Obviously, this is expected, but I need a way to force the values to change to 1 or 100.

Is this possible? I have not been able to find any questions or examples on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Sample Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  basicPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- data.frame(val1 = c(10,100,1000),
                   val2 = c(4,5,6))
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(
    df,
    rownames = FALSE,
    editable = list(target = "cell"),
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not possible. I am the one who implemented the numeric editing in **DT** tables. When you double-click on a cell to edit it, that creates a numeric input and then it is destroyed after you finish the edit. There's no control on this numeric input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is not possible with the built-in numeric editing. But there's a solution using the Javascript plugin [CellEdit](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit). I'm assuming you want to allow a limited number of choices, for example 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000. Then with **CellEdit** you can have a dropdown list to choose a number among these ones.

Download the file [dataTables.cellEdit.js](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/tree/master/js).

By default, the interface is not very stylish. To style it, copy the CSS code below and put it in a file **dataTables.cellEdit.css**, in the same folder as **dataTables.cellEdit.js**.

```css
.my-input-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.my-confirm-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.my-cancel-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #a94442;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now, here is the code of the app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 10, 10),
  Y = c("a", "b", "c")
)

callback = JS(
  "var tbl = $(table.table().node());",
  "var id = tbl.closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {",
  "  var cellinfo = [{",
  "    row: updatedCell.index().row + 1,",
  "    col: updatedCell.index().column + 1,",
  "    value: updatedCell.data()",
  "  }];",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo', cellinfo);",
  "}",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  },",
  "  inputTypes: [",
  "    {",
  "      column: 0,",
  "      type: 'list',",
  "      options: [",
  "        {value: 1,     display: '1'},",
  "        {value: 10,    display: '10'},",
  "        {value: 100,   display: '100'},",
  "        {value: 1000,  display: '1000'},",
  "        {value: 10000, display: '10000'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }",
  "  ]",
  "});"
)

path <- path.expand("www") # the folder containing 'dataTables.cellEdit.js' 
                           # and 'dataTables.cellEdit.css'
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js",
  stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css", 
  all_files = FALSE
)

# Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable <- datatable(
      dat, callback = callback, rownames = FALSE, selection = "none",
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
    )
    dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
    dtable
  }, server = FALSE)  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: dataTables.cellEdit]

Comment: This is great! I had considered using this sort of approach but I don't really have the skills the implement something like this myself. Thanks for taking the time to put this together, it looks nice and functions well.