# I want to make the edits in datatable in R Shiny not free text and limited to certain values

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I found this answer very very helpful, but how to adapt it to two or more columns

[Is it possible to restrict the values that can be used in an editable datatable in Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053373/is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-values-that-can-be-used-in-an-editable-datatable/77059441#77059441)

Thank you

I tried expanding the inputtypes but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet:

```
callback = JS(
"var tbl = $(table.table().node());",
"var id = tbl.closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
"function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {",
"  var cellinfo = [{",
"    row: updatedCell.index().row + 1,",
"    col: updatedCell.index().column + 1,",
"    value: updatedCell.data()",
"  }];",
"  Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo', cellinfo);",
"}",
"table.MakeCellsEditable({",
"  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
"  columns: [0,1,2],",
"  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
"  confirmationButton: {",
"    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
"    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
"  },",
"  inputTypes: [",
"    {",
"      column: 0,",
"      type: 'list',",
"      options: [",
"        {value: 1,     display: '1'},",
"        {value: 10,    display: '10'},",
"        {value: 100,   display: '100'},",
"      ]",
"    },",
"    {",
"      column: 1,",
"      type: 'list',",
"      options: [",
"        {value: 1,     display: '1'},",
"        {value: 10,    display: '10'},",
"        {value: 100,   display: '100'},",
"      ]",
"    },",
"  ]",
"});"
 )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).